# Path connectedness, metrizability and path lengths

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, connectedness

I was wondering if there is some way to topologically construct a path connected space where it is possible to measure the lengths of the paths? Like, if a space is metrizable and path connected, can you measure the path lengths? If not, what else is needed?

Comment: This might be interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. In a metric space you can define the length of any continuous curve (which could possibly be $+\infty$).

You use the concept of *absolutely continuity*. If $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to X$ is a continuous curve, define
$$
\ell(\gamma) = \sup\left\{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} d(\gamma(t_{k+1}),\gamma(t_k))\colon n\in \mathbb N, 0=t_0<t_1<\dots <t_n=1\right\}.
$$

If $\gamma$ is a differentiable (or even lipschitz) curve in $\mathbb R^n$ one can prove that
$$
\ell(\gamma) = \int_0^1 |\gamma'(t)|\, dt
$$